# Google play services are lost and a notification said it has been set to stop

Tags: google-drive

Today on my one day old new Android smart phone I tried to update goggle play services and it stopped updating and could not find update page anywhere in the play store and then I got an error message that said google play services is now in stop  and so I looked in my google play store account apps and it was deleted and also it was deleted in my settings app list so I searched for google play services hoping to reinstall but when I tapped it a new app is there called play services info and I also checked on my computer if the app would be in play store but it was the same new app play services info. With no google play services I cannot access many important apps. How can google play services be put back in the google play store so I can download it to be able to use many important apps.

Comment: I tried to post this question yesterday and later found a resoluton

Answer (score 0):

I did a factory reset and then I checked my settings app list and google play services was back, but it is only enabled and the force stop, clear data and clear cache are not working but all that matters is my apps that require Google play services working I can use again like messenger, Gmail and more. Since the factory reset to google play store it is still not found there and when it comes time for an update for google play services then my apps will not work and I am good for now but need to solve the issues that are critical to my device.